# List files with creation date and modification in DOS?

Tags: cmd, dos

With this command I can list all files in all sub directories:

```
dir /b /a-d /s *.*
```

In this list, I need to include two columns: creation and last modification date of each file. How could I do this?

Comment: Probably can't with the DIR command w/o a fancy batch file. VBS and FileSystemObject may be the way to go. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa242706(VS.60).aspx The examples are VBA but VBS syntax is close.

Answer (score 0):

You would be wasting this second column because both columns would have to display the same date!
MS-DOS simply does not maintain separate creation and modification dates.

Comment: I'm guessing the original poster isn't actually using MS-DOS and has confused the Windows command problem with it.